# ARM When using reference() in an copy iterator, arm template parser seems to break

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have written a ARM template that dynamically builds out the app settings based on a JSON object parameter.  This allows for adding any app setting without having to modify the template:

parameters.json

```
   {
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {    
        "app_settings": {
          "value": {
            "keyvalue_pairs": [
              {
                "name": "appsetting1",
                "value": "value"
              },
              {
                "name": "ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey",
                "value": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

chopped down working template.json file

```
 "resources": [
    {
      "comments": "",
      "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
      "kind": "web",
      "name": "[variables('app_service_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[variables('hiddenlink_app_service')]": "Resource"
      },
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "ApplicationId": "[variables('app_service_name')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[concat(variables('app_service_name'),'/stage-slot')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "stage-slot"
      },
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('app_service_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
        "siteConfig": {
          "copy": [
            {
              "name": "appSettings",
              "count": "[length(parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs)]",
              "input": {
                "name": "[parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs[copyIndex('appSettings')].name]",
                "value": "[parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs[copyIndex('appSettings')].value]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }      
    }
```

I now try and conditionally reference the app insights instrumentation key on my app settings hoping to override the app insights instrumentationkey from the resource.

```
"siteConfig": {
            "copy": [
              {
                "name": "appSettings",
                "count": "[length(parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs)]",
                "input": {
                  "name": "[parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs[copyIndex('appSettings')].name]",
                  "value": "[if(equals(parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs[copyIndex('appSettings')].name,'ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey'),reference(variables('appInsightsResource')).InstrumentationKey,parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs[copyIndex('appSettings')].value)]"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
```

This started throwing errors saying the if statement needs a boolean first parameter, but I didnt see anything wrong with it so I tried the following snippet and it worked so it leads me to believe that the use of the "reference()" inside a conditional isnt valid:

```
"siteConfig": {
            "copy": [
              {
                "name": "appSettings",
                "count": "[length(parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs)]",
                "input": {
                  "name": "[parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs[copyIndex('appSettings')].name]",
                  "value": "[if(equals(parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs[copyIndex('appSettings')].name,'ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey'),'testvalue',parameters('app_settings').keyvalue_pairs[copyIndex('appSettings')].value)]"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
```

Additionally if I remove the whole "if()" and explicitly put "`reference(variables('appInsightsResource')).InstrumentationKey`" into the value, it outputs the right value so I know that this reference() call works but seems to break down when added inside an "if()" conditional statement.

The question is, is there any way to get this to work?  I am trying to dynamically set the Instrumentation key while keeping in tact the ability to pass in a JSON object for my app settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing extremely confusing results with copy properties construct in general. most of the times is blows up with absolutely cryptic errors.

You won’t be able to use the `reference()` function in the `count` property – the copy loop is expanded at compile time – reference is evaluated at run-time. also, today I cant reproduce my working example, but i had a working example of reference function working in a copy properties, without `if()` though. You might want to create a bare minimum example showing how this doesnt work (so only 1 resource ideally). If that doesnt work you might want to raise an issue on github and\or azure feedback

You might be able to work around this by using nested deployments. but generally using properties copy in a clever way is a bit of a pain, due to compile\runtime issues.

Comment: I did manage to get the reference function working without an If, but the moment I put it inside the if, weird errors start popping up.  I am going to  maybe dedicate a couple more hours to this but im at least getting validation that this may be a limitation of arm templates in general.

Comment: yeah, sometimes you cant make anything out of it, sadly :(